# Insert (Google ad) token in a template

Tags: views, theming, tokens

I want to insert a token from the [Google Ad Manager](http://drupal.org/project/google_admanager) module in a view.

But how do you insert a token like the ad_slot token in this module in a views template?

Comment: have you looked at `token_replace()` ?

Comment: Yes, i couldnt make it work. How should it be used? 
I could only find documentation on how to use it with tokens provided by the node: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7

In this case, the token is provided by module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Ad Manager module uses a filter for the tokens, not the Token module. You could call its internal function `$content=_google_admanager_substitute_tags($text);` to do the substitution for you, where you replace $text with `[google_ad:ad_slot]` but I am not sure if it will know enough to put all the google js in your page. Try it out, I guess.

Otherwise, you can do something like `$content=theme('google_admanager_block', $gid, $google_ad);` where `$gid=variable_get('google_admanager_account','');` and `$google_ad` is your ad slot. That I've done all over the place myself with reasonable success.

Comment: I've just tried both ways with no result.

Comment: if you do a `print 'hello world';` does it show up, eg, to make sure everything else is working.  if you look at your resulting html, does the rest of the google javascript show up in the header of the page, eg, a `[script]` tag containing the GA_googleFetchAds() and so forth.  If not, something else is amiss as well.

Comment: Just checked the source code and it prints the following:
<div id="gam-holder-c" class="gam-holder"><script type="text/javascript">GA_googleAddSlot("c", "c");</script><script type="text/javascript">GA_googleFillSlot("c");</script></div>
So it prints the script, but not with the ad_slot info.

In the header it shows:

GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-xxxx", "ad_slot_of_another_slot_normally_placed_with_blocks");


Currently this is what i have in php:
 $google_ad = the_ad_slot_id;
 $gid = variable_get('google_admanager_account','');

 
 echo theme('google_admanager_block', $gid, $google_ad);

Comment: well something is turning $gid and $google_ad into "c" somewhere....so I'd check your php code...also, the AddSlot is only set when cache is set in the theme function, and you don't seem to be doing that here, so something else is amiss "in there" as well...and perhaps it's because all of my suggestions have been for the drupal 6 version...if you are running drupal 7, functions/arguments might be different etc, too

Comment: if it is d6 v d7, a quick look in the code says that its theme args are more along the lines of  `array('id' => $gid, 'ad_slot' => $google_ad)` so try that instead of `$gid, $google_ad`.

Comment: that's it!! It works with array('id' => $gid, 'ad_slot' => $google_ad). Thanks a lot

Comment: sweet! I'll learn D7 eventually :)